# Duplicated Control Name Causing 'Not A Member' Compile Errors

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, custom-controls

I have created a custom control called MultiTextbox.  When I place my control onto a form and try to run my project, I get the following errors:

```
'MultiTextBox' is not a member of 'MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox'.
Type 'MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox' is not defined.
```

In my Form1.Designer code, I can see the following issues:

```
Me.MultiTextbox1 = New MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox()
Me.MultiTextbox1.ObjectAlignment = MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox.ObjectPlacement.Left
Me.MultiTextbox1.Style = MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox.TextboxStyle.Normal
Friend WithEvents MultiTextbox1 As MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox
```

I don't understand why it is duplicating the Control name for a selected few items.

The properties it is referring to are custom properties based from Enums.
For example:

```
       Public Enum ObjectPlacement
            Left
            Right
        End Enum

    Private m_ObjectAlignment As ObjectPlacement = ObjectPlacement.Left

'ObjectAlignment
<Browsable(True), Category("Appearance"), _
Description("The text to display as an input group header.")> _
Public Property ObjectAlignment As ObjectPlacement
    Get
        Return m_ObjectAlignment
    End Get
    Set(value As ObjectPlacement)
        If m_ObjectAlignment = value Then Return
        m_ObjectAlignment = value
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

**UPDATE**

If I place my custom control on a form and run, everything will work fine without error, but as soon as I modify my control in any way (e.g. Size, Style, etc.) it gives me errors, and I can't even run the application as the compiler just sits in an infinite loop saying 'Building...'.  I have to force quit VS.

Comment: Did you manually declare a `Namespace MultiTextbox` around your MultiTextbox class?

Comment: No I did not.  I simply called all my `Imports` then `Public Class MultiTextbox` then I went straight into my code.  Should I have declared a Namespace?

Comment: No. That was my first guess for a duplicated name.

Comment: But why : Friend WithEvents MultiTextbox1 As  MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox  and not just : Friend WithEvents MultiTextbox1 As MultiTextbox

Comment: I'll bet the root namespace for your `MultiTextbox` control is `MultiTextbox`.  But why do you care how the designer does its job?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes you are correct.  Root namespace is called MultiTextbox.  I don't really care about the designer, it's just that I can not run my app because the designer is placing a duplicated name (MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox) when I add the control to a form and therefore won't compile.  Should my Root Namespace be called something different?  I have always called my Root Namespace the same as my application or control.

Comment: @CristiC777 The duplicated name is getting placed there by VS and not by me.  It automatically creates that entry when I add my control to a form.

Comment: re **UPDATE** that probably doesnt have anything to do with the "double name" (which is actually the fully qualified `NameSpace.ClassName`).  If you wait it out (~30 sec), you should see an output message saying it cant replace xxx because it is in use; maybe the message is there are you dont see it.  This happens sometimes and might be aggravated by some solution settings or config you are using if it happens a lot.  Partly seems to depend on how you stopped the last debug run.

Comment: Okay it looks like I had two separate issues here.  I ended up removing the Root Namespace and left it blank (I remember reading that somewhere) and that cleared up all the errors.  The infinite looping error on trying to build my project was due to a code error on behalf (triggering a repaint inside a paint event).  It didn't throw any errors but simply causes a continuous loop of the control refresh.  Thanks for your help.  Not sure how to mark this as complete.

Comment: @Riples Answer the question with as much information as you can provide, that may help other people with a similar problem understand the issue. Then mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some useful posts on this thread and some googling, I found that by removing the Root Namespace from my project it removed all of my compiler errors that I was getting regarding a duplicated namespace (MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox):

```
Me.MultiTextbox1 = New MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox()
Me.MultiTextbox1.ObjectAlignment = MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox.ObjectPlacement.Left
Me.MultiTextbox1.Style = MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox.TextboxStyle.Normal
Friend WithEvents MultiTextbox1 As MultiTextbox.MultiTextbox
```

[image]

Secondly, the lockups that I was experiencing when trying to build my project was due to me setting a button's visible state within my paint event causing an infinite refresh loop of my control.